# Why it is not compile time constant?

Tags: java, compile-time-constant

```
final int i=10;
final String s=new String("lkj");
```

Why first is compile time constant but second is not compile time constant even if final is used with second one as well?

Comment: Because the JLS says so: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Comment: Because the string variable stores a reference not a value in this case (see the "new" keyword"). So every time you run your program, the reference value is different.

Comment: JB Nizet 5, this is a perfect answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @RoundSauce3 no, that's not the reason. if you use `final String s = "ljk"`, than `s` is a constant expression, although it also is a reference to a String object.

Comment: So I guess the answer is "because they felt like it". :P

Answer (score 5):

Because [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) says so:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type String (§15.16)
> - The unary operators +, -, ~, and ! (but not ++ or --) (§15.15.3, §15.15.4, §15.15.5, §15.15.6)
> - The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
> - The additive operators + and - (§15.18)
> - [... other cases]

But none of the cases says "Strings created by invoking the String constructor taking a literal String as argument".

There is no reason to ever call that constructor anyway (and it should be deprecated, IMHO).

Comment: So is final String s="ll"; a compile time constant

Comment: `"ll"` is a constant expression, if that's what you're asking, since it's a String literal. If you have a class with `static final String s = "ll"`, then `s` is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no constant at compile time. There will be a value when it is called at **runtime** after a new instance of the string was created.

Generally: Using "new" will create a new **instance**. And an instance is not a class but an object at **runtime**.

Comment: So is String s="ll"; a compile time constant

Comment: Yes. This is a literal string like JB Nizet described.